# How to get all permissions for one Facebook application?

Tags: facebook

I'm trying to get all the permissions a user must provide to accept one Facebook application in question. Does anyone know how can I do that ? (I have the appId and the appSecret)

Comment: Not sure what you mean here. A user does not have to give all permissions an app asks for – especially the extended ones he can deny right in the Auth dialog, and he will still be connected to the app.

Comment: I'm trying to get only the permissions the user has to accept to run the application (not the extended ones)

Comment: View this Page https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions , You have get details about User and Extended Facebook permissions

Comment: _“only the permissions the user has to accept to run the application”_ – there is no such thing. An app can ask for additional basic(!) permissions every time it feels like in the Auth dialog. (Or are you talking about the permissions set in the app dashboard, that affect only login from the app center?)

Comment: Yes I'm talking about the "User & Friend Permissions" that you set in the app dashboard, in "Configuring Permissions". The user has to accept them to authentificate the application, so I'm wondering if we can get that list from a request to Facebook giving the app ID and the app Secret.

Comment: what do you mean 'get the list from a request'? do you mean a call to `/me/permissions` to see which permissions you were granted?

Comment: what the question is asking, is not possible.  There is no endpoint returning the permissions the application requires to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question. I write it down in case someone has the same problem one day.

I just had to do a FQL query. There are two fields "auth_referral_user_perms" and "auth_referral_friend_perms" in the table *application* corresponding to what I was looking for : the "User & Friend Permissions" that we set in the application dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/APP_ID/permissions).

Using the PHP SDK :

```
  $facebook->api('/fql', 'GET', array(
         'q' => 'SELECT auth_referral_user_perms, auth_referral_friend_perms FROM application WHERE app_id = ' . APP_ID,
         'access_token' => TOKEN
         ));
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: This will show the permissions requested by the application, but not the ones required for the application to function necessarily.